# Select intersecting features within Value Relation Widget

Tags: qgis, widget, value-list

Is it possible to filter records in the Value Relation Widget to include only those that intersect the current feature?

[image]
We are trying to set up a layer for user input where we need to populate Start/End cross-street intersections. I can use the Value-Relation widget to bring up a list of all the Street-Names from the master-roads layer, but I'd like to reduce it to jus those roads that intersect the feature being edited. As per this example, sometimes the road changes name at either side of the intersection, so for consistency it would be best if manually selected by the data-entry person rather than automatically populating and just ending up with the first match (or whatever a computer decided!).

I'm not sure if the filter expression can be used in this way, but it'd be great if it can. I've tried a few expressions but so far no success.